# IBM Openwhisk, Unable to extract route parameters

Tags: node.js, serverless, openwhisk, ibm-cloud-functions

Hello everyone I have deployed a function on IBM cloud and I am calling it via web api however all the function works fine except for those that involve route parameters as I am unable to extract them. I am using the serverless framework and when calling the variable `__ow_path` it returns empty. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

`serverless.yml` file:

```
getById:
  handler: handler.getById
  overwrite: true
  annotations:
    web-export: true
  events:
    - http: 
        method: GET
        path: /users/{userid}
        resp: http
```

`handler.js` file:

```
module.exports.getById = async (params) => {
    return {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            params,
            msg: params.__ow_path,
            created: new Date()
        }),
        statusCode: 200
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the URL you are using to call the web action?

Comment: @JamesThomas heres the url: 
https://a41db28b.eu-de.apiconnect.appdomain.cloud/users/newuser

Comment: What version of `serverless-openwhisk` do you have installed?

Comment: I am using version 0.18.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please upgrade the `serverless-openwhisk` package to version [0.18.3](https://github.com/serverless/serverless-openwhisk/releases/tag/v0.18.3). This is due to a [known bug](https://github.com/serverless/serverless-openwhisk/commit/31b8d8aab41b264a744b3f5bc2e81e19c3cb3adf) introduced in 0.18.

The example above is valid.

Comment: After updating to 0.18.3 I am getting the path but it does not return a 404 if route is not found. For example my route is `users/{userid}` but on accessing the following route `users/{userid}/details` it still returns the previous endpoint instead of a 404.

Also I was wandering if there's a way to get path params as key value pairs.

Comment: Sub-paths (`/details`) on existing paths need to handled manually by the action. 
There is an open issue to provide path params as explicit parameters (https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk/issues/3593) but this isn't implemented yet.

Comment: One more thing, the param `__ow_body` is also not accessible in post request. The  req body params are present but they are not wrapped inside `__ow_body`.